# I want to use Office365 Graph APIs, In order to do so I am using Powershell, However Connect-Graph cmdlet throws error

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to connect to Office365 environment using modern auth, hence I will have to use Graph API services.

I had installed powershell modules required for same. And in my Windows Powershell ISE Connect-Graph is available via intellisense which means the modules got installed successfully.

However when I am running the command Connect-Graph it results into error :

```
Connect-Graph : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system 
cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-Graph
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-Graph], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Aut 
   hentication.Cmdlets.ConnectGraph
```

It looks like it wants the files of System.Net.Http with version 4.1.1.2 which it cannot find. I am just guessing the error.

And when I run this command `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http` it runs succesfully which means the files are present maybe not the correct version, However I cannot find the current version of assembly to validate that.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Powershell are you using? There is a difference between assemblies used in PS for Windows and other versions.

Comment: @bluuf its Powershell 5.1

Comment: Could you please have a try to open your Powershell ISE with administrator and run the command again ?

Comment: I am running with admin privileges only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I also have ps 5.1 and have no issues running connect-graph, I can only assume that you may not have the correct .net framework versions installed. Make sure you have the proper .net framework versions installed, maybe try to install the latest 4.8 framework. since I have that installed.

Comment: Thanks! Updating the .net framework to 4.8 resolved the error :)